# Understanding how functions with lists work

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
def trick(l,i):
    if i==1:
        return l[0]
    else:
         return l[1]
def foo(x):
    x[0]='def'
    x[1]='abc'
    return x[1]
q=['abc','def']
print (trick(q,1)==foo(q))
print (trick(q,1)==foo(q))
print (trick(q,0)== foo(q))
```

When I run this it prints True, False, True. But since foo() always returns the same thing shouldn't it be True,True, False. Is one of these functions changing the input list q somehow? Because the return from any of these functions should be independent of the original list.

Comment: Yes, `foo` modifies the `q` list.

Answer (score 4):

Given that `list`s in Python are *mutable*, if you pass a `list` into a method, behind the scenes, you're actually passing the reference to that `list`, which means if you mutate the `list` in the method, you are mutating the `list` for everyone who *references* that list.

Consider the simple example:

```
def foo(lst):
    lst[0] = 3

test_list = ["hello", "world"]
print test_list # prints ['hello', 'world']
foo(test_list) # mutates `test_list` by setting `test_list[0] = 3`
print test_list # prints [3, 'world']
```

In your case,

```
def trick(l,i):
    if i==1:
        return l[0]
    else:
         return l[1]
def foo(x):
    x[0]='def'
    x[1]='abc'
    return x[1]
q=['abc','def']

# in the below line, Python first evaluates `trick(q, 1)`
# which returns 'abc'. Then Python evaluates `foo(q)`, which
# mutates `q` to `['def', 'abc']` and returns the new `q[1]`,
# or 'abc'. Therefore, this statement evaluates to `True`.
print (trick(q,1)==foo(q))

# in the below line, Python evaluates `trick(q, 1)` with the
# newly mutated `q` and so returns 'def'. `foo(q)` again modifies
# `q` to `['def', 'abc']` and returns 'abc'. Therefore, the statement
# evaluates to `False`.
print (trick(q,1)==foo(q))

# this last statement evaluates to True because `trick(q, 0)` returns
# 'def', which is the same as what `foo(q)` returns.
print (trick(q,0)== foo(q))
```